# proving that $x \rightarrow x^e \pmod m$ is not one to one

Tags: finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, totient-function, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $m=pq$ where $p,q$ are primes. Prove that if $e$ is not coprime to $\phi(m)$, then the mapping $x \rightarrow x^e \pmod m$ from $Z_m^*$ to $Z_m^*$ is not one-to-one.

My attempt: Let $s,l$ be integers s.t $e = sg$ and $\phi(m) = lg$ for $g = \gcd(\phi(m),e)$. then for any $x \in Z_m^*$ we have $({x^l})^e = x^{lsg}=({x^{\phi(m)}})^s \equiv 1^s \pmod m \equiv 1 \pmod m$
So if i can show that $x^l \not\equiv 1 \pmod m$ for some $x$, i found two distinct element in the group who are both mapped to 1
Since I know that $g > 1$ then $l < \phi(m)$, meaning I have to find an element with order $> l$, and I am stuck there, and since I haven't used $\phi(m) = (p-1)(q-1)$ I guess it has something to do with it. Any guidance?

Comment: $$x \to x^e \neq 1 \to 1$$

LOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much group theory do you know?  This is actually a consequence of a general fact about abelian groups.  I'll post the answer here, and maybe someone else (or you) can distill it down to your special case.

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$.  Suppose $\gcd(e,n) > 1$, where we can--without loss of generality--assume $2 \leq e \leq n$ (so $e$ is "small").  Thus there must be some prime $r$ such that $r \mid e$ and $r \mid n$.  Since $r \mid n$, there exists an element $a \in G$ of order $r$ by Cauchy's (or Sylow's) Theorem.  Since $r \mid e$ we have $e=rk$ for some integer $k$.

Consider your function $f: G \to G$ via $f(x)=x^e$, which is a homomorphism as $G$ is abelian.  Now, if $1$ is the identity element of $G$ (which I'm avoiding calling $e$ for obvious reasons) we have $f(1) =1^e =1$.  On the other hand, $f(a) = a^e = a^{rk} = (a^r)^k=1^k=1$. Since $a \neq 1$, $f$ is not one-to-one.

Your result comes from this one under the dictionary:
$$
G = \mathbb{Z}_m^*
$$
$$
n = \varphi(m).
$$

**Edit/Addendum:**  Here's the distilled version for you.  Take $f: \mathbb{Z}_m^* \to \mathbb{Z}_m^*$ via $f(x)=x^e$ where $d=\gcd(e,\varphi(m))>1$.   We may write $e=dk$ and $\varphi(m) = dj$ for some integers $k$ and $j$.  By Euler's Theorem, $x^{\varphi(m)} = 1$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}_m^*$.

Now, **any** $j$th power of **any** element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_m^*$ will map to $1$ under $f$.  This is easy to see:
$$
f(x^j) = x^{je}= x^{jdk}  =(x^{jd})^k=(x^{\varphi(m)})^k = 1^k=1.
$$
Now just convince yourself that not all $j$th powers can be equal, so we have at least two different elements mapping to $1$.  That does it.  (Maybe this is equivalent to your effort posted in your question.  If so, sorry if it's not helpful.)

Comment: Thanks! Cauchy's theorem is what I was missing... Which is weird because we weren't taught that in class.
However, about the second part, all the $j$th powers can be equal in some cases ($p=5,q=3,e=6$) so I think using Cauchy's theorem is mandatory in this case

Comment: @user2263786  If your instructor gives a different solution w/o invoking Cauchy, I would be interested in hearing it.